# Absolute positioned element creating overflow on it's scrollable container

Tags: html, css, overflow, absolute

I've a long table that needs horizantal scroll. On it's last column I've buttons that show absolute positioned tooltips on hover. When the table itself doesn't initially create scrollbar, hovering the button, and showing it's tooltip, does.

```html
<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red; padding: 20px; overflow-x: auto">
        <div style="background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative">
            My table that needs a scrolling parent div, but often times fits into the screen while it's buttons are not on hover
            <div style="position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; top: 50px; left: 350px">
                My table button's tooltip that appear on hover.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the above example. It makes sense for overflow-x to do it's thing and show the absolute element for visibilty. But it doesn't make sense, when I think that an absolute element is out of normal flow therefore overflow shouldn't take account of it.

Without going down the road of toggling overflow-x visible and scroll based on the table's width, What can I do in my case? Is there any CSS solutions for an absolute element to be not accountable in an overflow scroll?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get a better idea of what's going, would you be able to include the table code, and then put all of your code into a runnable snippet that the community could use to help diagnose?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left: 350px;` and add `right: 0;`